# How Does date time column behave when column contains empty value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have encountered some problem , when i passed an empty value to date time variable it stores as default date(1900-01-01 00:00:00.000)

i wrote a conditional statement that

```
declare @l_date datetime = '',@l_date1 datetime = getdate()

if @l_date <> ''
   select 'Yes' as '@l_date',@l_date D
else
   select 'No' as '@l_date',@l_date D

if @l_date1 <> ''
    select 'Yes' as '@l_date1',@l_date1 D
else
    select 'No' as '@l_date1',@l_date1 D
```

I expected both should be return "Yes". Unfortunately 1st condition returns "No" and 2nd condition returns "Yes". Can anyone explain the functionality how does it works.

Comment: It's probably because the string is automatically casted to an INT and SQL Server returns 0 for an empty string. You should use NULL instead.

Comment: Thank you @dnoeth.

Comment: Thank you @Larnu

Answer (score 2):

There is no `''` value for a `datetime`. `''` will be implicitly cast the to the value `19000101`, as you've seen. if you have an unknown date, use `NULL` (`NULL` does mean "unknown" after all). This changes your statement to:

```
DECLARE @l_date datetime, --I don't set the value as it'll already be NULL
        @l_date1 datetime = GETDATE();

IF @l_date IS NOT NULL 
    SELECT 'Yes' AS [@l_date],
           @l_date AS D;
ELSE
    SELECT 'No' AS [@l_date],
           @l_date AS D;

IF @l_date1 IS NOT NULL 
    SELECT 'Yes' AS [@l_date1],
           @l_date1 AS D;
ELSE
    SELECT 'No' AS [@l_date1],
           @l_date1 AS D;
```

(Note this still returns `'No'` and `'Yes'` respectively.)

Answer (score 2):

The [documented default value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql) is used for temporal types when an empty string is specified. Consider:

```
DECLARE
     @datetime datetime = ''
    ,@smalldatetime smalldatetime = ''
    ,@datetime2 datetime2 = ''
    ,@date date = ''
    ,@time time = ''
    ,@datetimeoffset datetimeoffset = ''
SELECT
     @datetime AS datetime
    ,@smalldatetime AS smalldatetime
    ,@datetime2 AS datetime2
    ,@date AS date
    ,@time AS time
    ,@datetimeoffset AS datetimeoffset;
```

Result:

```
+-------------------------+---------------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------------+------------------------------------+
|        datetime         |    smalldatetime    |          datetime2          |    date    |       time       |           datetimeoffset           |
+-------------------------+---------------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------------+------------------------------------+
| 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 1900-01-01 00:00:00 | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 1900-01-01 | 00:00:00.0000000 | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00 |
+-------------------------+---------------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------------+------------------------------------+
```

Although zero is sometimes used instead of empty string to denote a default value, this is not allowed for the newer `datetime2`, `date`, `time`, and `datetimeoffset` types.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
declare @l_date datetime=0 ,@l_date1 datetime = getdate()

if @l_date IS NOT NULL
   select 'Yes' as '@l_date',@l_date D
else
   select 'No' as '@l_date',@l_date D

if @l_date1 IS NOT NULL
    select 'Yes' as '@l_date1',@l_date1 D
else
    select 'No' as '@l_date1',@l_date1 D
```